# Problem initializing 4-bit mode LCD(DEM 20486 SBH-PW-N)

Tags: avr, lcd

I've got an ATMEGA16 with a LCD display DEM 20486 SBH-PW-N ([datasheet](http://goo.gl/ZJ048I)) connected to port C like so

- C0 - RS
- C1 - RW
- C2 - E
- C3 - not Set
- C4 - D4
- C5 - D5
- C6 - D6
- C7 - D7
  D0-D3 are grounded

I haven't been able to find much detailed information on how to work with the LCD and I've been trying this for a good two days, so any information as to what I've been doing wrong would be helpful.

```
#define LCDPORT PORTC
#define LCDPIN PINC
#define LCDDDR DDRC
#define RS 0
#define RW 1
#define EN 2

#define D4 4
#define D5 5
#define D6 6
#define D7 7

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void LcdFlash() {  // Flash enable flag
    LCDPORT |=  (1<<EN);
    _delay_ms(2);
    LCDPORT &= ~(1<<EN);
    _delay_ms(2);
}

void LcdSendNibble(char cmd, char rs) {
    LCDPORT &= ~(1<<RW); // Write mode
    if(rs)
        LCDPORT &= ~(1<<RS); // Command mode
    else
        LCDPORT |=  (1<<RS); // Data mode
    LCDPORT |=  (cmd<<D4);
    LcdFlash();
}

void LcdInit() {

    LCDDDR |=  (1<<RS);     // SET(LCDDDR, RS);
    LCDDDR |=  (1<<RW);     // SET(LCDDDR, RW);
    LCDDDR |=  (1<<EN);     // SET(LCDDDR, EN);
    LCDDDR |=  (0x0F<<D4);  // ASSIGN(LCDDDR, D4, 0x0F);

    _delay_ms(150); //Wait for boot
    //Function set
    LcdSendNibble(0b0010, 0);
    LcdSendNibble(0b0010, 0);
    LcdSendNibble(0b0100, 0); //N = 0, F = 1
    _delay_ms(50);

    // Display on/off control
    LcdSendNibble(0b0000, 0);
    LcdSendNibble(0b1100, 0); //D = 1, C = 0, B = 0
    _delay_ms(50);

    // Display clear
    LcdSendNibble(0b0000, 0);
    LcdSendNibble(0b0001, 0);
    _delay_ms(50);

    //Entry mode set
    LcdSendNibble(0b0000, 0);
    LcdSendNibble(0b0110, 0); //I/D = 1 SH = 0
    _delay_ms(50);
}

int main() {
    LcdInit();
    while(1) {}
}
```

I would also appreciate information as to what some of the different flags mean during the initialization.
specifically the line-mode flag N and the shift flag SH.

My goal is simply to get the screen to light up, and then to write a character to the first position though this is not attempted in the first place

Comment: This LCD looks like it's compatible with the HD44780. You should be able to find plenty of information online about that part…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's Hitachi [HD44780](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller)-compatible you need to study the [data sheet](http://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/output_devices/44780.pdf) very carefully and follow it to the letter and it will work. There should be plenty of stuff on the net for an AVR if you want to copy, but I think it's best to figure it out (tm).

Also, make sure you've got the contrast voltage input set to a reasonable value (near ground for normal temperature range units). The datasheet you linked is a bit confusing as it shows 4.5V for Vo. Note that voltage is relative to Vdd, so for a 5V supply it should be about 0.5V with respect to ground.

Comment: V0 is set fine, I've got a test hex where the thing works but I can't figure out how to get the initialization part done.
How do I know if it's HD44780 compatible?

Comment: Almost surely it is, but you can compare the datasheet for the module with the chip datasheet I linked above. If it's a clone the module manufacturer may prefer not to mention it. Be generous (and confirm) timing delays to begin with.

Comment: I recently studied the HD44780 and I had a question about a the include file I wrote with some help of tutorials. I think it's quite good commented and that it might be helpful.
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138680/why-using-a-pointer-interfacing-lcd-hd44780